# How to return multiple rows from the stored procedure?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle10g

```
 "select tableshow from alltable where branch =      
 '"+session.getAttribute("Branch")+"' and sem = 
 '"+session.getAttribute("Sem")+"'";
```

through this query i am fetching the name of the table for example let the table name be 'fifthsem' which is stored in exe variable

now i need to apply query on this variable exe as a table name.
i need to fetch the whole data from procedure  of this table and show in jsp page.

using oracle database

Answer (score 2):

> How to return multiple rows from the stored procedure?

You can use [REF CURSORs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10767/procedures_plsql.htm#TDPNG60035) to return multiple rows from the stored procedure to a client application.

> Using REF CURSORs is one of the most powerful, flexible, and scalable ways to return query results from an Oracle Database to a client application.
>
> A REF CURSOR is a PL/SQL data type whose value is the memory address of a query work area on the database. In essence, a REF CURSOR is a pointer or a handle to a result set on the database. REF CURSORs are represented through the OracleRefCursor ODP.NET class.

View this example : [Retrieving an Oracle cursor in Java](http://www.andrels.com/wp-en_US/2010/01/retieving-an-oracle-cursor-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to a variable and get data using dynamic sql

Refer this [Dynamic SQL LOOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090673/dynamic-sql-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle Pipelined table functions.

For details on how to create a Pipelined table function in oracle, refer [this link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions)