# pl sql select * from owner.view1 minus select * from owner2.view1 as a cursor in for loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c1
 IS
   SELECT view_name
   FROM all_views
   WHERE owner = 'DBA_A'
   AND view_name LIKE 'IRV_%'
   OR view_name LIKE 'RD_%'
   ORDER BY view_name;
BEGIN
 FOR i IN c1
 LOOP
   FOR ii IN ('select * FROM DBA_A.' || i.VIEW_NAME || ' minus select *     FROM DBA_B.' || i.VIEW_NAME)
   LOOP
     -- I plan to put the results from the select in the FOR ii loop in a listAgg.  I think I can figure that out.
     dbms_output.put_line(listAgg);
   END LOOP; -- for ii
 END LOOP; -- for i
END;
```

I get the following error.  Its probably syntax of which I'm exploring but is what I'm trying to do in the ii loop look sane?  I have to work out how to use the listAgg function.

Thank you.

Error generated at END LOOP; -- for ii

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

The dbms_output.put_line shows the proper select is generated. Thanks again. Rich

Thank you Aleksej.  The tables/views have many fields.  But I'm looking to compare views not the tables.  The views are in two separate schema.  Both schema objects are exactly the same (I copied DBA_A to DBA_B).  But I modified a base table for one view in one schema.

The select * from DBA_A.view1.... minus select * from DBA_B.view1... works if I hard code the select/minus with hard coded schema.view names.  The select returns one row of the view with the changed data.  I believe there is a way to return all column names of a view (within the loop).  I wish to do a dbms_output.putline (via a listAgg) on the list of column names and the data from the row(s) returned.

I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough.  Thank you very much for your example code.  I'll modify mine my code per your example and post my results.

Comment: Your code has some issues, but it's not clear what you need to do, so it's hard to help you. Say that you have found a view with the first query, then you make the minus and get, say, 10 records with 5 columns. What do you want to do  with these records? How can you handle the fact that you don't know in advance the columns that your dynamic query will return? Please try to build a [mcve] to help people to help you

Comment: Hi.  When I just do a (outside of any code block) select...minus...select (manually coding it with select * owner.view minus select * owner2.view) on a view where I changed a base table in one schema the select returns rows with all the columns.  I just want to get the rowid for the rows returned within the ii loop and do a dbms_output.put_line(rowid). The code never makes it into the ii loop. I hope that helps.  Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic SQL LOOP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090673/dynamic-sql-loop)

Comment: The rowid of a view does not make much sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to simplify your question, just to give you some hints on dynamic code

Say I have tables I want to compare in couples; I use tables to avoid the rowid issue and I use the same schema, simply changing the table names, for simplicity.
The tables:

```
create table TABLE_A_1(id) as select 1 from dual union all select 2 from dual;
create table TABLE_A_2(id) as select 2 from dual;
create table TABLE_B_1(id) as select 3 from dual union all select 3 from dual;
create table TABLE_B_2(id) as select 4 from dual;
```

Say I want to compare TABLE_A_1 against TABLE_A_2 and TABLE_B_1 against TABLE_B_2, checking for the id value; I believe this can give you an idea on a way to use dynamic SQL:

```
declare
    cur sys_refcursor;
    v   number;
begin    
    for tab in ( select table_name from user_tables where regexp_like (table_name, 'TABLE_[AB]_1') ) loop
        open cur for 'select id from ' || tab.table_name || ' minus select id from ' || replace(tab.table_name, '1', '2');
        loop
            fetch cur into v;
            exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
            dbms_output.put_line( tab.table_name || ' minus ' || replace(tab.table_name, '1', '2') || ': ' || v);
        end loop;
    end loop;
end;
```

This gives:

```
TABLE_A_1 minus TABLE_A_2: 1
TABLE_B_1 minus TABLE_B_2: 3
```

Notice two main simplifications here:

- I assumed that all the tables have a single field; in a more general case, you have to ensure that the views that you compare have the same structure.
- I used the `ID` to identify the missing rows; in a table, I could have used `rowid`, but on views `rowid` will not be useful, so you need to find a way to identify the rows in a view missing in the other.

In a word, to give a complete solution I should know more about your views and the way you want to use to identify missing rows; without these informations, this contains some hints that could hopefully be useful to you to write your own solution.

Comment: Thank you Aleksej,

Comment: If the answer is right for you, please accept it. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you find something on what to do when someone answers you.