# Oracle dynamic cursor in for in loop

Tags: oracle, loops, dynamic, cursor

I have a procedure that have to select from different tables according to a input parameter. Input parameter select the table I have to query. Actually I have a static situation.

```
CURSOR c IS SELECT ... FROM TBL;
BEGIN
FOR idx IN c LOOP
....
END LOOP;
```

Is there a way to change cursor query definition at run time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic SQL LOOP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090673/dynamic-sql-loop)

Comment: Is it just the table name which changes or do you want to change the columns in the projection as well?

Comment: For now I solved using the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE .... USING. So